# ReactJS Image Gallery with lazy load, full screen and position changing with drag n drop

Tags: reactjs, npm, drag-and-drop, lazy-loading, image-gallery

I am looking for a npm module which is capable of

- Lazy load the images
- Full screen
- Grid like in the image below
- Drag and Drop to reposition in the grid

I've found some packages such as https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-lazy-load-image-component, http://neptunian.github.io/react-photo-gallery/examples/basic-rows.html but they do only one thing from the list above.

[image]

Do you have any suggestions of an npm module or how to achive those functionalities ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe its a bit late but this package should have all the features except the drag and drop function:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-grid-gallery

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29794857)